Comparing Values from different groups
I Want to compare the values of each group from the same query. The aim is to detect if all the groups have the same values, e.g.



User_id
Item
Remark




1
AM180
Good


2
AM180
Good


3
AM180
Good


1
AM181
Moderate


2
AM181
Moderate


3
AM181
Moderate


1
AM182
Poor


2
AM182
Poor


3
AM182
Poor



The output of the above table should be 1 since all the users have the same *Remark *for each Item.
The following 2 examples illustrate a mismatch and should return 0 as result:



User_id
Item
Remark




1
AM180
Good


2
AM180
Good


1
AM181
Moderate


2
AM181
Moderate


3
AM181
Moderate


1
AM182
Poor






User_id
Item
Remark




--------
------
--------


1
AM180
Good


2
AM180
Moderate


3
AM180
Good


1
AM181
Moderate


2
AM181
Poor


3
AM181
Moderate


1
AM182
Poor


2
AM182
Good



In other terms, I need to compare many group if they are identical in terms of number (user_id = 1, 2, 3) for each Item and having the same remark in each group.
Any help please?
Result = 1 if the groups are identical, otherwise 0

WITH RemarkCounts AS (
        SELECT 
            Item,
            COUNT(DISTINCT Remark) AS DistinctRemarkCount
        FROM 
            remarks_table
        GROUP BY 
            Item
    )
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN DistinctRemarkCount = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS result
    FROM 
        RemarkCounts;


Is this really for SQL Server? I get 'Msg 130 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

Updated the answer to make it SQL Server compliant
